# How to display data from database into joomla article

Tags: joomla3.0

I have used chronoform to insert and save information. Now i need to display all the information.
If we can display it in joomla article then how to get information from database into article
or is there any other way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simplest way to install [ARI data tables](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ari-data-tables)